# How to Dynamically Change pytest's tmpdir Base Directory

Tags: python, pytest, temporary-files

As per the [pytest documentation](https://pytest.org/dev/tmpdir.html#the-default-base-temporary-directory), it possible to override the default temporary directory setting as follows:

```
py.test --basetemp=/base_dir
```

When the `tmpdir` fixture is then used in a test ...

```
def test_new_base_dir(tmpdir):
    print str(tmpdir)
    assert False
```

... something like the following would then be printed to the screen:

```
/base_dir/test_new_base_dir_0
```

This works as intended and for certain use cases can be very useful.

**However, I would like to be able to change this setting on a per-test (or perhaps I should say a "per-fixture") basis.  Is such a thing possible?**

I'm close to just rolling my own `tmpdir` based on the [code for the original](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/_modules/_pytest/tmpdir.html), but would rather not do this -- I want to build on top of existing functionality where I can, not duplicate it.

---

As an aside, my particular use case is that I am writing a Python module that will act on different kinds of file systems (NFS4, etc), and it would be nice to be able to yield the functionality of `tmpdir` to be able to create the following fixtures:

```
def test_nfs3_stuff(nfs3_tmpdir):
    ... test NFS3 functionality

def test_nfs4_stuff(nfs4_tmpdir):
    ... test NFS4 functionality
```

Comment: Broken link. Current link [pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/tmp_path.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There didn't appear to be a nice solution to the problem as posed in the question so I settled on making two calls to `py.test`:

- Passing in a different `--basetemp` for each.
- Marking (using `@pytest.mark.my_mark`) which tests needed the special treatment of using a non-standard basetemp.
- Passing `-k my_mark` or `-k-my_mark` into each call.

Answer (score 3):

In the sources of `TempdirFactory` the `.config.option.basetemp` is used as the attribute to store the `basetemp`. So you can directly set it before the usage:

```
import pytest
import time
import os

def mktemp_db(tmpdir_factory, db):
    basetemp = None
    if 'PYTEST_TMPDIR' in os.environ:
        basetemp = os.environ['PYTEST_TMPDIR']
    if basetemp:
        tmpdir_factory.config.option.basetemp = basetemp
    if db == "db1.db":
        tmpdb = tmpdir_factory.mktemp('data1_').join(db)
    elif db == "db2.db":
        tmpdb = tmpdir_factory.mktemp('data2_').join(db)
    return tmpdb

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def empty_db(tmpdir_factory):
    tmpdb = mktemp_db(tmpdir_factory, 'db1.db')
    print("* " + str(tmpdb))
    time.sleep(5)
    return tmpdb

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def empty_db2(tmpdir_factory):
    tmpdb = mktemp_db(tmpdir_factory, 'db2.db')
    print("* " + str(tmpdb))
    time.sleep(5)
    return tmpdb

def test_empty_db(empty_db):
    pass

def test_empty_db2(empty_db2):
    pass
```

-

```
>set PYTEST_TMPDIR=./tmp
>python.exe -m pytest -q -s test_my_db.py
* c:\tests\tmp\data1_0\db1.db
.* c:\tests\tmp\data2_0\db2.db
.
2 passed in 10.03 seconds
```