# How to create folders using fixtures with pytest?

Tags: python, directory, pytest, fixtures

I need some folders to be created for the test cases that I am running. I have created them using this code:

```
def check_folder_existence(path):
    if not os.path.isdir(path):
        os.mkdir(path)

def test_create_folders():
    """
    Create needed folders for test output
    """
    output_path = "data/output"
    if not os.path.isdir(output_path):
        check_folder_existence(output_path)
```

But I want to create them more professionally, using pytest fixtures. How can I refactor the code, so that the effect is the same? (the creation of folders for tests)

Comment: https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/tmpdir.html Here's the fixture for tmp folders with some examples. :)

Comment: @h4z3 here the directory is created in the temp directory. Can I create a temporary folder at a given path, inside the current project's directory?

Comment: The docs also show how to pass a custom location for the term dir when starting the tests... but some people actually checked sources how to hijack those and change in the code itself - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566968/how-to-dynamically-change-pytests-tmpdir-base-directory

Comment: @h4z3 but this is still in the temp directory, just with a different name for the directory. I would like to create a directory in the tests folder, the one I am running my tests from.